# Auto click a button Javascript

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-modules

I have a module for prestashop that opens a tab when it is selected.
Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://examplewebsite/pluginsdk.js"></script>
{include file='./_partials/test.tpl'}
{if $boxes|count}
    <table class="resume table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{l s='Select box' mod='boxselection'}</td>
                <td> 
                    <button type="button" name="boxselection_id" id="showBoxLocation" data-country='{$hostCountry}' class="button-exclusive btn btn-default">
                        {l s='Show Box location' mod='boxselection'}
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id="box_name" name="box_name" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="box_address" name="box_address" value="">
                    <span style="padding-bottom: 10px;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 22px;width:100%;display:block" id="showBoxDetails"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{/if}
```

I tried to use this code:

```
<script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var button = document.getElementById('showBoxLocation');
        button.click();
      }
</script>
```

But it only works half.
If I select the option to open the tab with the Button it doesn't work. No auto-click. But if I refresh the page the auto-click works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this `
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var button = document.getElementById('showBoxLocation');
            button.click();
    });
`

Comment: Thank you very much, but it is working exactly the same. it is clicked only if the tab with the button is opened and then refreshing the page. When I open the tab no auto-click.

Comment: can you please tell me in detail about tab, button and working steps that you need?

Comment: OK sure. So I work on a prestashop 1.6.1.24. On the checkout page I have more cariers but one has a module because he uses lockers. When I select that carrier a tab opens that has a button to press so you can open the map with all the lockers and you choise a locker from the map. the problem is that if you don't press the button to open the lockers map when you checkout and finish the order the seller won't know where to send you the products you orderd. So that is why that button must be auto-pressed.